# Display latest "commentator" username in forum app [Django]

Tags: python, django, orm

I am creating a forum app, and want to display latest commentator's username(as seen in screenshot):

[image]

But I have some gaps in information, here is my code so far:

### Models

```
class Forum(models.Model):
"""
Forum Model
"""
forum_author = models.ForeignKey(
    Profile,
    related_name='user_forums',
    null=True,
    blank=True,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE
)

forum_title = models.CharField(
    max_length=225,
    verbose_name=u'Thread Title',
    blank=False,
    null=False
)

forum_category = models.ForeignKey(
    'Category',
    verbose_name=u'Thread Category',
)

forum_content = MarkdownxField()
```

---

```
class Comment(models.Model):
"""
Comment Model
"""
forum = models.ForeignKey(
    'Forum',
    related_name='forum_comments'
)

comment_author = models.ForeignKey(
    Profile,
    related_name='user_comments',
    null=True,
    blank=True,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE
)

comment_content = MarkdownxField()

created_date = models.DateTimeField(
    default=datetime.datetime.now,
)
```

---

### Forum list views - display all threads

```
...
from app_forum.models import Forum, Comment    

def forum_list_view(request):
        forum_list = Forum.objects.all().order_by("-misc_created")
        return render(request, 'app_forum/forum_list.html' {'forum_list': forum_list})
```

My single thread views :

```
def forum_single_view(request, pk):
forum = get_object_or_404(Forum, pk=pk)
forum_comments = Comment.objects.filter(forum=forum.id)
paginator = Paginator(forum_comments, 10)
page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
try:
    forum_comments = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    forum_comments = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    forum_comments = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
return render(request, 'app_forum/forum_single.html', {'forum': forum, 'forum_comments': forum_comments})
```

Comment: what is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the latest comment by

```
   L_comment = Comment.objects.latest('created_date')
```

You can get the commented user by

```
   L_comment.comment_author
```

If you want to get the latest comment in a particular forum then,

```
   forum = Forum.objects.get(forum_title='forum-title')
   latest_comment = forum.forum_comments.latest('created_date')
   author = latest_comment.comment_author
```

**Updates:**

Much better option is to define a method in your Forum Class, like this:

```
   def latest_comment_author(self):
          return self.forum_comments.latest('created_at').comment_author
```

And you can access it from the template by

```
    {{ forum.latest_comment_author }}
```

Comment: Thank you, it's almost works! But instead it diplay same latest comments author and date on every thread. And also, where **comment_set** come from? Thanks

Comment: Then it would be better to use the method @julio specified in his answer by creating a method in your **Forum** Model Class. And I am sorry, my mistake, it isnt necessary to suffix **_set** if you have specified a related name in your foreign key. I'll update my answer

Comment: Thank you, but still not working :( . It display nothing in my template..

Comment: **UPDATE** My mistakes! I put it under Comment class, not Forum class. Now it's working like a charm! Thank you! :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use the related object manager for this. Create a method on your Forum model to retrieve the latest comment on the forum. Something like:

```
@cached_property
def latest_coment(self):
    return self.forum_comments.order_by('-created_date').first()
```

Then you can call this method on your template to get the latest comment on it

Comment: Thank you. But, how I should call it in template? I try `{{ latest_comment.comment_author }}`, but it shows nothing.